# How to use Django JSON and GeoJSON Serializer?

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I am relatively new to Django. I have read the documentation but I'm still having trouble getting it to work.

**views.py**

```
def getMarkers(request):
    query = request.GET 
    zoom = query.__getitem__('zoom')
    fromlat = query.__getitem__('fromlat')
    tolat = query.__getitem__('tolat')
    fromlng = query.__getitem__('fromlng')
    tolng = query.__getitem__('tolng')
    querystring = coordinate.objects.filter(lat__gt=fromlat) .filter(lat__lt = tolat).filter(lon__gt = fromlng).filter(lon__lt = tolng)
    data = serialize('geojson', querystring,
          geometry_field='point',
          fields=('name',))

    print(data)
```

**models.py**

```
class coordinate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=7)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=7)
    latlng = [lat, lon]
    zoom = models.IntegerField(default=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

how do I use the searlizer? It's not throwing an error but I know it's not working because nothing is getting printed to the server terminal except the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(data)` won't work. You have to do something like:

```
return HttpResponse(data)
```

Then visit the URL of that view and you'll see the result.

**Update**

`MultiValueDictKeyError` occurs if the key that you're trying to access is not in `request.GET` or `request.POST`.

To prevent this error, make sure your `GET` request has `zoom` key. For that you will need to write the URL in addressbar something like this:

```
/getmarkers/?zoom=val&formlat=val&somekey=val
```

Replace `val` with the value for that key.

Comment: Im getting a MultiValueDictKeyError at /getmarkers/ for zoom. Any ideas how to deal with that?